# are webtemp.xml files necessary if you only want to provision SharePoint sites programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

On a current project, I am looking to provision SharePoint sites only using the API; not through the web UI. Do I still need a webtempxxx.xml file or will the onet and other resources suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sites using stsadm or through the API using templates that have the visible property set to "false" in the webtemp*.xml files.  The webtemp*.xml files control what templates are visible through the UI, either in Central Admin when creating a site, or when creating subsites.

I probably wouldn't actually delete the webtemp*.xml files.  That just sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim - I *thought* webtemp*.xml files were just for the UI.

I had no intention to delete any, just wondered if I *had* to create them if all I ever want to do is provision sites programmatically.